# How to create a php page with frames?

Tags: php, html, frame, lamp

```
<html><head></head>

<frameset cols="30%,*">
<frame src="menu.php">
</frameset>
</html>
```

This is my index.php page. And the menu.php page lists a set of clients from mysql.

I want to create a hyperlink with the result of the mysql query. And when you click on the mysql, it should call content.php and display the contents in the second frame.

But so far, on clicking the hyperlink, it redirects the menu frame to the other php page.

Basically, I am trying to create a menu on the left hand frame and display contents of each listing on the right frame.

Comment: You would use PHP wise method `<? include "menu.php" ?>` rather than using the frame.

Comment: The only time i can think of using frames is if you wanted music playing the background without refreshing and having music in the background is a horrible idea anyway. Do what user said, include files if you must, but don't use frames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use frames. They're a hideous throwback to the "old" days. It's easy to replicate the few benefits frames provided with PHP includes (dynamic/constant sidebars/menus/content shared across multiple pages), without ANY of the long list of drawbacks that frames have.

Comment: There are times when it's appropriate to use frames (not saying this is one of them). For example if you want a wrapper around a frame .. updating the page using ajax would be pretty insane.

Comment: @Tandu: all it takes is a sane page layout and an ajax-style full refresh is quite easy. There aren't any usage cases these days where full-blown frames are justified.

Comment: any quick links on how to make a sidebar/menu in php?

Comment: @Marc B you would have to have to have the ajax trap all page changes from the loaded page, load the xml from that page, strip off duplicate scripts/headers, and display that page in the container. With forms, it gets even more complicated. You would also have to worry about the possibility of conflicts in IDs, scripts, and css.

Answer (score 1):

Frames are a huge mess. However, if you must, you can give your frames `name`s, then specify a `target` attribute on the links in the menu frame to say which frame it should open in.

Also, don't use frames.

Comment: Could you point me to a tutorial for making a sidebar menu in php? Thanks, everyone is telling me not to use frames, but not the alternative. I just want a static menu on the left hand side of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with php - it is simple html.
You have to use **target** atribute in your `<a>` links.
Your code will be something like:

```
<frameset cols="30%, 70%">
<frame src="menu.php">
<frame src="content.php" name="content">
</frameset>
```

link in your menu.php will be:

```
<a href="content.php?page=somepage" target="content">Somepage</a>
```